# Activating WooCommerce causes 500 internal server error

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to install WooCommerce, but when I try to activate it, I get a 500 Internal Server Error. 
I've tried installing it via the Plugin Search in the admin panel, and FTP, but both result in the same error.

To check if it was a plugin conflict, I tried installing WooCommerce on my local development version of the website containing all the same plugins, but no problems arose.

I've tried increasing the memory limit in the wp-config file using `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');`, but that didn't solve the problem either.

To try to get more out of the 500 error page I enabled debug mode, but that didn't result in any more information being displayed.

Any ideas as to why it won't activate?

Comment: Any messages in the http-server error log?

Comment: A few saying that the maximum execution time of a different plugin had been exceeded.  Just in case that was the problem I deactivated that plugin, but WooCommerce still won't activate.

Comment: Have you checked file permissions? I have seen missing execution permission causing 500 error (this depends on the web-server configuration)

Comment: Which files would you suggest checking?

Comment: Woocommerce php files

Comment: The permissions are correct.